# this code always go to else I tried to put if in if to force code to go to it but still go to else

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
def multiple(x, y):
    return x * y
def subtrack(x, y):
    return x - y
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y
print('select your operation please')
print('1-Add')
print('2-Multiple')
print('3-subtrack')
print('4-Divide')
chose=int(input('enter your selection please: '))
num1=int(input('enter your first num please: '))
num2=int(input('enter your second num please: '))

if chose == '1':
    print(num1,'+',num2,'=',add(num1,num2))
elif chose == '2':
    print(num1,'*',num2,'=',multiple(num1,num2))
elif chose == '3':
    print(num1, '-', num2, '=', subtrack(num1,num2))
elif chose == '4':
    print(num1,'/',num2,'=',divide(num1,num2))
else:
    print("invalid number operation")
```

this code always go to else I tried to put if in if to force code to go to it but still go to else some solutions please

Answer (score 1):

When doing:

`if chose == '1'`

You're comparing to a char in python.
If you do
`if chose == 1`
you're actually comparing to a int. Which is also what you enter in the inputs.
removing the `'` around the right hand side of your if comparison operators, you will not keep getting pushed to the 'else' statement!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language this is but `chose` is an `int` an your if checks on an `string`(or `char` depending the language).

if you change your comparison to:

```
if chose == 1:
    print(num1,'+',num2,'=',add(num1,num2))
elif chose == 2:
    print(num1,'*',num2,'=',multiple(num1,num2))
elif chose == 3:
    print(num1, '-', num2, '=', subtrack(num1,num2))
elif chose == 4:
    print(num1,'/',num2,'=',divide(num1,num2))
else:
    print("invalid number operation")
```

It should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving user input and converting to `int` and while comparison you are comparing it with string i,e. `if chose == '1':`

the solution is:

1. You receive user input in `int` or compare the integer value

```py
    chose = int(input('enter your selection please: '))
    if chose == 1:
        print(num1,'+',num2,'=',add(num1,num2))
    elif chose == 2:
        print(num1,'*',num2,'=',multiple(num1,num2))
    elif chose == 3:
        print(num1, '-', num2, '=', subtrack(num1,num2))
    elif chose == 4:
        print(num1,'/',num2,'=',divide(num1,num2))
    else:
        print("invalid number operation")
```

2.You receive user input in `str` and compare the string value

```py
    chose = str(input('enter your selection please: '))
    if chose == '1':
        print(num1,'+',num2,'=',add(num1,num2))
    elif chose == '2':
        print(num1,'*',num2,'=',multiple(num1,num2))
    elif chose == '3':
        print(num1, '-', num2, '=', subtrack(num1,num2))
    elif chose == '4':
        print(num1,'/',num2,'=',divide(num1,num2))
    else:
        print("invalid number operation")
```